# run hadoop command in bash script

Tags: bash, hadoop

i need to run hadoop command in bash script, which go through bunch of folders on amazon S3, then write those folder names into a txt file, then do further process. but the problem is when i ran the script, seems no folder names were written to txt file. i wonder if it's the hadoop command took too long to run and the bash script didn't wait until it finished and go ahead to do further process, if so how i can make bash wait until the hadoop command finished then go do other process?

here is my code, i tried both way, neither works:

```
1. 
listCmd="hadoop fs -ls s3n://$AWS_ACCESS_KEY:$AWS_SECRET_KEY@$S3_BUCKET/*/*/$mydate | grep s3n | awk -F' ' '{print $6}' | cut -f 4- -d / > $FILE_NAME"                            
echo -e "listing... $listCmd\n"                                                                                                                                                   
eval $listCmd
...other process ...

2. 
echo -e "list the folders we want to copy into a file"
hadoop fs -ls s3n://$AWS_ACCESS_KEY:$AWS_SECRET_KEY@$S3_BUCKET/*/*/$mydate | grep s3n | awk -F' ' '{print $6}' | cut -f 4- -d / > $FILE_NAME
... other process ....
```

any one knows what might be wrong? and is it better to use the eval function or just use the  second way to run hadoop command directly

thanks.

Comment: Does "hadoop fs -ls s3n://$AWS_ACCESS_KEY:$AWS_SECRET_KEY@$S3_BUCKET/*/*/$mydate" have any output?

Comment: yes, when run that hadoop command directly, it ran well

Answer (score 2):

I would prefer to `eval` in this case, prettier to append the next command to this one. and I would rather break down `listCmd` into parts, so that you know there is nothing wrong at the `grep`, `awk` or `cut` level.

```
listCmd="hadoop fs -ls s3n://$AWS_ACCESS_KEY:$AWS_SECRET_KEY@$S3_BUCKET/*/*/$mydate > $raw_File"
gcmd="cat $raw_File | grep s3n | awk -F' ' '{print $6}' | cut -f 4- -d / > $FILE_NAME"
echo "Running $listCmd and other commands after that"
otherCmd="cat $FILE_NAME"
eval "$listCmd";
echo $?  # This will print the exit status of the $listCmd
eval "$gcmd" && echo "Finished Listing" && eval "$otherCmd"
```

`otherCmd` will only be executed if `$gcmd` succeeds. If you have too many commands that you need to execute, then this becomes a bit ugly. If you roughly know how long it will take, you can insert a sleep command.

```
 eval "$listCmd"
 sleep 1800  # This will sleep 1800 seconds
 eval "$otherCmd"
```

Comment: Using eval is the only way I was able to start the Hadoop streaming using a bash script